# Removing the "Previous" and "Next" based on the current slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow

I am trying to remove/hide the "previous" or "next" buttons, based on the current slide.

If the user has reached the end, he will only be able to move backwards and if he is at the beggining, he can only go forward.

I am using the AnythingSlider jQuery Plugin. It can be found here: http://css-tricks.com/anythingslider-jquery-plugin/

The JavaScript code can be found here: https://github.com/CSS-Tricks/AnythingSlider/blob/master/js/jquery.anythingslider.js

Hover, I would prefer to pass an argument to the anything slider function. Because I believe it would make it more user friendly (specially for those who will read this question in the future).

Basically we are talking about adding a new option.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is in the documentation. You have to search a bit for it :).

Here's a jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/ycUB6/85/

```
$('#slider').anythingSlider({

    // if false, the slider will not wrap
    infiniteSlides: false,

    // If true & the slideshow is active, the  slideshow will stop on the last page. This also stops the rewind effect  when infiniteSlides is false.
    stopAtEnd: true

});​
```

Comment: I dont look for a such easy way. "Use the Force, Luke"! :)

Comment: Damn... I'm going to shoot myself for this!! Sorry for such a stupid distraction of mine.

Answer (score 3):

So lets start from logic thinking. What we need to find? After clicking next slide button we need to hide next arrow. Or if Prev Slide button and it's first image - we need to hide prev button. So.. seems like at first we need to find scrolling page actions.
I looked through the code (oh God... 900 lines) and found finally such code on **line 518**:

```
base.gotoPage = function(page, autoplay, callback, time) {
```

This function called to scroll page from one to another. So we 'need to go deeper'. In code we can found navigation updating function. **Line 569**:

```
// Set visual
if (o.buildNavigation){
    base.setNavigation(base.targetPage);
}
```

And all we need is to add new function of hiding arrows with a simple check if it is last page or first. Lets go (after **line 572** insert):

```
if (o.showNullArrows){
    base.hideNullArrows(base.targetPage);
}
```

So here we binded action. Lets scroll a little down and paste full function code. For example, after **line 692**:

```
base.hideNullArrows = function(page){
    if(page==0) 
        base.$back.hide();
    if(page==base.pages) 
        base.$forward.hide();
};
```

Ok, now we have full working binded action call after changing page. But.. there are still another function to scroll pages! **Line 660**:

```
base.setCurrentPage = function(page, move) {
```

Hm.. I guess.. now you know what to do now with this one. Good luck :)

Answer (score -1):

You should try looking at the code yourself and just create an if statement somewhere in the middle and also try to find some kind of key that tells which image you on.

Comment: That is what I am doing right now. If I solve this issue myself, I will answer my own question. I haven't quit yet.

However, I am having a really hard time doing it. That is why I placed the question here.